# libgdx Isometric point to grid and check blocked tiles collision

Tags: java, android, libgdx, isometric

Basically Ive got an isometric map and my player fixed and centered in the middle of the screen always. To check for collisions, I first convert the point to map coords, then use those coords to check if the tile itself, depending on which way the player is moving, has properties that contain the word "blocked". If yes then stop movement (return to oldposY and oldposX)
Well, it works, sort of. My player stops on tiles that dont contain "blocked"
Every time the player stops in this video the code is detecting that he hit a tile with the properties marked "blocked", however this is wrong.

Here is a video showing the problem in action:
http://youtu.be/FG12KGw_eg4

I am printing my x,y coords in the top left of the screen and it shows my x and y increasing or decreasing even if I'm traveling in just one direction. So for example, If I'm walking only to the Right on my screen, the x AND y both increase when you'd think only the X should be increasing. This is true for any direction traveled, up, up-right, left, up-left, etc.. I don't know if that helps but I think that means the MapUtils.toIsometricGridPoint function is not working properly. 
 Would it simplify this at all knowing that my character player is fixed always at the center of the screen?

On with the code. Here is my method MapUtils.toIsometricGridPoint

```
/** converts point to its coordinates on an isometric grid
    *  @param point the point to convert
    *  @param cellWidth the width of the grid cells
    *  @param cellHeight the height of the grid cells
    *  @return the given point converted to its coordinates on an isometric grid */

/** @see #toIsometricGridPoint(Vector2, float, float) */
   public static Vector3 toIsometricGridPoint(Vector3 point, float cellWidth, float cellHeight) {
      Vector2 vec2 = toIsometricGridPoint(point.x, point.y, cellWidth, cellHeight);
      point.x = vec2.x;
      point.y = vec2.y;
      return point;
   }
```

Here is how I implemented it in my Player class to find the tiles that are marked blocked using the toIsometricGridPoint code:

```
    private boolean isCellBlocked(float x, float y) {
    Vector3 touch = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    Play.camera.unproject(touch); //the touch variable has nothing to do with touch atm, it's just what it's called.
    MapUtils.toIsometricGridPoint(touch, collisionLayer.getTileWidth(), collisionLayer.getTileHeight()); //collisionlayer is a layer on my map obviously
    Cell cell = collisionLayer.getCell((int) touch.x, (int) touch.y);
    return cell != null && cell.getTile() != null && cell.getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked"); //a string Ive marked some tiles properties with in my tiled map editor
    }
```

and finally the code used to check for and then react to a collision (depending on direction traveled):

```
public boolean collidesRight() {
        for(float step = 0; step < getHeight(); step += collisionLayer.getTileHeight() / 2)
                if(isCellBlocked(getX() + getWidth(), getY() + step)){
                   Gdx.app.log("Found Blocked Tile", "Yes");
                   return true;
                }

             return false;
```

It detects collision in strange places, BUT it IS detecting tiles that are marked with my string "blocked", but it's detecting these tiles and stopping the player in the wrong places and it is not working correctly. It's almost as if it has somehow shifted its tile detection off of what the map looks like visually.